# Как передать параметры из JavaScript в CMD и запустить программу?

Tags: javascript, cmd, html-application

Есть приложение на `.hta`, к нему необходимо добавить функцию удаленного просмотра процессов, это можно реализовать с помощью данной программы -

https://bitbucket.org/html-applications/lan-admin/src/default/utils/RTC/

Запуск программы осуществляется с командной строки вида:

```
rtc.hta [host] [/service|device] [/noFileInfo]
```

Как можно реализовать это? Заранее благодарю.

Comment: JS не может передавать параметры в консоль. Если бы это было возможно, то представьте себе, как было бы опасно заходить на неизвестные сайты.

Comment: @LEQADA, JavaScript существует не только в браузерах, он может быть встроен в любое приложение, так же как и Lua. В данном случае на файлы .hta не распространяется политика безопасности обычных браузеров, так как тут в дело идет IE с его ActiveX возможностями.

Comment: @AlexKrass, интересно. Вот, значит, почему все плюются на ActiveX. Спасибо за информацию.

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться ActiveX и вызвать программу через WScript.shell.

```
shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
shell.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]);
```

Конечно при условии, что пользователь даст согласие на небезопасные операции.

Comment: спасибо), все получилось, а еще вопрос можно? Есть программа на .hta, пингующая компьютеры, как к ней добавить функцию подкрашивания поля ввода (если ответ на пинг - положителен то покрасить в зеленый цвет, если нет то красный)                   <input type="text" id="ComputerName" name="host" onchange="ping()">

var PingTimeout      = 400;   // Таймаут для ping при подключении к удалённому компьютеру (мсек)
wsh.Run ('ping.exe /n 1 /w ' + PingTimeout + ' ' + Host.value)

Comment: @AllanianShade, а как Вы собираетесь узнавать, прошел пинг или нет? Вызываемая через Run программа должна иметь какие-нибудь средства, для сообщения о результате своих действий: либо возвращать код процесса, либо записывать свой результат куда-нибудь. В случае со служебной утилитой ping,exe, можно только [перенаправить ее вывод](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Перенаправление_ввода-вывода) в файл и [потом его прочитать](http://scriptcoding.ru/2013/04/29/rabota-s-tekstovymi-fajlami/) и распарсить. Другого мне на ум не приходит.